# How to call some api url with some header in it using the bat file?

Tags: api, batch-file

Following is the bat file code for executing the URL from a bat file. I wanted to send the header with the URL. How can I send the header with it?

```
@ECHO OFF
SET BROWSER=firefox.exe
SET WAIT_TIME = 2
START %BROWSER% -new-tab 
"http://localhost/warmup/api/Event/eventsLoc/17.4575262/78.373212/1221"
@ping 127.0.0.1 -n %WAIT_TIME% -W 1000 > nul
pause
```

please help.

Comment: Do you need to display the page and use an actual browser?

Comment: not exactly.. but i need to hit the api.

Comment: As stated in the answer below you need to use a program like CURL.  WGET would also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se) instead of Firefox.

It is designed for command line so :

1. you can run it silently (without opening a window)
2. there are much more options for the command line, such as specifying the HTTP call method (GET, POST, PUT...) and as you required the header.

example from the [doc](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html)

```
curl --header "Destination: http://nowhere" http://example.com
```